# How best to interact with peripheral from browser

Tags: browser, applet, sandbox, twain, image-scanner

This may be a very elementary question, I apologize in advance.  I need to interact with a device from a web app.  More specifically a twain device.  Currently I use a signed java applet for this.  It generally works well; the signed applet works on multiple platforms and provides the device interaction needed.  The issue I have is that applets do not seem to be long for the browser world, at least in allowing non-sandboxed access like this.  I need to know what other options are available.
The requirements I would really like to meet are

- can access local devices. Code signing certificate is not a problem.
- is primarily web based. As long as it can be delivered via web, and be initiated via web app going forward, we are OK.
- be cross platform.  Currently I can use scanners on macs and PCs via twain, and linux machines via sane.

I am not familiar with technologies such as flash and silverlight.  Are either of these viable options? Is anything?

Answer (score 0):

Right now I only know of ActiveX, Applet, or browser extensions that are available (just search the web, and pick the one that looks good to you).  Pretty soon I'd imagine that Flash, and Silverlight options will be available, but I know of none as of right now.